# How to get multiple values out of if else condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, nested, conditional-statements

I want to get two values out from the function for a specific condition (on "As_cm" values) and execute some operation on those values.  I could not do that.

```
function steelSection() {
    if (As_cm <= 29.2) {
       return [D  = 152.4, B = 152.2];
    } else if (As_cm <= 38.3) {
       return {D = 157.6, B = 152.9];
    } else {
      return [D = 1000, B = 2000];
    }
}
var d = D / 2;
var b = B / 2;
console.log(d);
document.getElementById("flangeWidth").innerHTML = d ;
console.log(b);
document.getElementById("depth").innerHTML = b ;
```

expected values for `As_cm <= 29.2`

`d= 152.4 / 2`

`b= 152.2 / 2`

The error message I get is

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at steelcolumn.js:68`

Comment: Well means it can not find the element

Comment: You're also never calling `steelSection()` + have a few syntax issues

Comment: That middle line's ending bracket: `return {D = 157.6, B= 152.9];}` doesn't have an opening bracket to go with it

Comment: In addition, you have syntax errors. If those aren't reported in the console, then you've made a mistake when transcribing the code here.

Comment: check first,if you have an element with ids flangeWidth and depth or not?

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object and then take the destructured properties as values.

```
function steelSection() {
    if (As_cm <= 29.2) return { d: 152.4, b: 152.2 };
    if (As_cm <= 38.3) return { d: 157.6, b: 152.9 };
    return { d: 1000, b: 2000 };
}

var { d, b } = steelSection();

document.getElementById("flangeWidth").innerHTML = d / 2;
document.getElementById("depth").innerHTML = b / 2;
```